# Qt moc_mainwindow

Tags: qt

I'm developing an application (with OpenCV) where I created a scroll bar and functions related but finally I deleted the scroll bar. The following error occures :

> moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to MainWindow::on_verticalScrollBar_actionTriggered(int)'
>
> moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to MainWindow::on_verticalScrollBar_sliderPressed()'
>
> :-1: erreur : release/moc_mainwindow.o: bad reloc address 0x4 in section `.data'
>
> collect2.exe:-1: erreur : error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks for help

Comment: Please read how to do a [mcve]

Comment: Press Clean all on the Build tab and then Run Qmake

Comment: @eyllanesc I 've cleaned the project but the error still remains. However, when I create empty functions corresponding to the ones "missing", the code runs of course but it's not optimal code of course

Comment: Based on the comments it sounds as if you've declared the slots `MainWindow::on_verticalScrollBar_actionTriggered` and `MainWindow::on_verticalScrollBar_sliderPressed` but have not defined/implemented them.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, you're right but the problem is that I deleted the scrollbar from  my interface but Qt shows an error about functions over sth that does'nt exist yet, and that's the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors `` undefined reference to `MainWindow::...' `` are caused by the fact that you have functions declared in `mainwindow.h` but not defined anywhere.

To fix this either define them in `mainwindow.cpp` or remove their declarations from `mainwindow.h`. If you do not have use for them obviously you should remove them.

---

Now about *"Qt shows an error about functions over sth that does'nt exist yet"* you might be referring to `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for ...`.

This might happen if you have one or more slots named `on_<objectName>_<signalName>` (e.g `on_verticalScrollBar_sliderPressed` and `on_verticalScrollBar_sliderPressed`) but the object `objectName` does not exist or it exists but has no signal named `signalName`.

This is caused by [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) which is called inside the call to `ui->setupUi()`. This function will try to connect every slot matching the `on_<objectName>_<signalName>` syntax and will write warnings to `stderr` (or the debug output) when it fails.

Also I strongly suggest you do not use `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` and the `on_<objectName>_<signalName>` syntax. If you use .ui files you cannot prevent the call to `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` as it is in generated code but if you do not use the syntax it will have no effect.
Instead you should connect signals and slots explicitly in your code.

See:

- [[QTBUG-49749] connectSlotsByName() misconnects slots when multiple children have the same name](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49749)
- [*"Proposal to change connectSlotsByName behavior"* in Qt developer mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2015-December/023924.html)